# I'm getting this error: Class "Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized" not found

Tags: magento2.4, zend-framework, php8

Not sure if it has to do with php 8.2 specifically or just php 8. My exception log is saying that it's not found here in this file but below is the code from line(s) 190 - 197. Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php:191

```
if (isset($params['qty'])) {
    $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
        ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
        )->getLocale()]
    );
    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
}
```

It was working in php 7.3 and so i honestly am not sure what it wants me to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace class **Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized** to **Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized**

magento 2 have update zend liberary to replace Magento framework filter classe. you can check it using the magento below path file.

```
vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard/Magento2/Sniffs/Legacy/_files/restricted_classes.php
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2DGm.png

Comment: if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Magento\Framework\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(

Comment: I'm still not quite certain what i need to do? Make the change like above? @Pankaj parmar